# JS Fetch posts only object ID to localhost

Tags: javascript, fetch

When I send form data using fetch, only the _id is registered in my database.

Using postman to post does send the correct data to the database. Also, the fetch posts to another server on heroku fine (I don't know how that server has been set up unfortunately).

With postman I've tried setting the Header content type to x-www-form-urlencoded, when that didn't solve the problem, I set the content type to json. That also did not work. The body Content-Type is set to x-www-form-urlencoded.

Using fetch to get the data from the express server (which has cors enabled) works fine. The data is also being correctly logged, so I'm pretty sure it's something with the post request....

```js
  sendToServer () {
    console.log(this.state)
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000`, {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        // also tried with 'application/json'
        'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
  }
```

Maybe this adds more clarity, the object I'm expecting is

```js
{
  "_id": "59adb44602416d102c095260",
  "title":"meetup",
  "date":"2017-09-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  "venue":"starbucks"
}
```

But instead I'm getting:

```js
{
   "_id": "59adb44c02416d102c095261"
}
```

The server code:

```js
//index.js

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const db = require('./db');
const router = require('./router');


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('express app listening on port 3000')
})

//router.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const controller = require('./controller')

router.get('/', controller.getAll)
router.post('/', controller.create)

module.exports = router;

//controller.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const EventModel = require('./model');

const getAll = async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await EventModel.find());
}

const create = async (req, res) => {
  const newEvent = EventModel({
    title: req.body.title,
    date: req.body.date,
    venue: req.body.venue,
  });
  await newEvent.save();
  res.send(newEvent);
}

module.exports = {getAll, create};

//model.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Event = new Schema({
  title: String,
  date: Date,
  venue: String,
}, {versionKey: false});

const EventModel = mongoose.model('Event', Event);

module.exports = EventModel;

//db.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cw-events', {useMongoClient: true});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Mongoose connected')
})
```

Comment: What `console.log(this.state)` prints?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, `JSON.stringify(this.state)` does not give the result you expect? Or is it really that `fetch` is malfunctioning when posting to `localhost`, as your title suggests?

Comment: You either want to send JSON, _or_ x-www-form-urlencoded - combining both makes little sense. What happens when you specify no `headers` at all, and leave this to the automatic intelligent detection that according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch should take place?

Comment: _“Using postman to post does send the correct data to the database. With postman I've set the Header content type to x-www-form-urlencoded and also the body.”_ - so you do not actually want to send JSON then …?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak It prints an object eg {title: "Meetup", date: "2017-09-06T00:00:00.000Z", venue: "Starbucks"}

Comment: @Bergi  JSON.stringify(this.state) gives the expected result, the fetch is malfunctioning when posting. I posted to another server set up on heroku and that worked fine although I don't know how that server's set up...

Comment: @CBroe I do want to send JSON. I initially set it to JSON but when that didn't work I tried xxx-form-urlencoded... but with application/json, it also doesn't post correctly

Comment: @Bergi so come to think of it if its posting to another server just fine, the problem is with my server.........

Comment: @IsabellaChen Where do you get the malformed output, can you show us the server code? Have you confirmed in your browser devtools (network panel) that the request is not the expected one?

Comment: @Bergi My network panel gives a status of 204 of type fetch and status 200 of type json... I'll put up the server code... using postman it posts to the server fine, and the front end also posts to another server on heroku fine... so I'm no longer sure where the problem is coming from...

Comment: I'm more interested in the content of the requests (headers and body), is that exactly the same as when sending through postman? And 2 status codes - are you running into CORS with a preflight when using localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that my problem was that I'd formatted the body-parser to parse requests from postman which were url-encoded. All I had to do was change it to json, so:

```js
//from this
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//to this
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

So now it parses json format, which is what the fetch is posting.